# How to send a JSON message via Python Requests/URL Module to a Pi Django server from a Pizero W on the same router/LAN?

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3+ and a Raspberry Pizero W connected to the same home wireless network.

The Pi 3+ is hosting a Django server, and the IP address of the Pi 3+ is static on the home network at `192.384.5.767`.

The Pizero W has a static IP address on the home network of `192.384.5.343`.

When I ping the Pi 3+ Server from the Pizero W, I can see that it is up:

```
pi@PIZEROW:~$ ping 192.384.5.767
64 bytes from 192.384.5.767: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=10.5 ms
64 bytes from 192.384.5.767: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=30.0 ms
64 bytes from 192.384.5.767: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=32.1 ms
```

Additionally, when I access the website hosted by the Django server on a tablet, there are no issues.

However, I need two-way communication between the Pizero W and the Django server so would like to test sending a super simple JSON message from the Pizero W to the Pi 3+ server and receive an acknowledgement from the server that it received the message.  I don't need the server to do anything with the message other than to receive it, discard it, and send a confirm that the message was received.

I tried doing this from the Pizero W using:

```
pi@PIZEROW:~$ python3
>>> import requests
>>> import JSON
>>> url = "http://192.384.5.767:8000"
>>> data = {'msg':'test'}
>>> r = requests.post(url, data)
```

And received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xb5a2b610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.384.5.767', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xb5a2b610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.384.5.767', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xb5a2b610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Not exactly sure what's going on, but it seems like despite the fact that the Django server is up and running as evidence by my tablet and the `ping` success, I still send and receive messages from the Pizero.

Any help / advice would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: I don’t think `192.384.5.767` is a real ip address. The numbers between the dots should be >=0 and <=255. Similarly 192.384.5.343

Comment: Correct, not the real IP address, but that's not really necessary for the purposes of this question, right?

Comment: My comment wasnt a real comment, so that makes us quits. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one of three things:

(1) your django server is not bound to the ip address or to 0.0.0.0.  Normally, the `runserver` command starts django listening on 127.0.0.1 or localhost.  To get it to bind to the correct ip address / port use

```
python manage.py 192.384.5.767:8000
```

In production environments, django applications are usually served with gunicorn or uwsgi and listening on port 80.  If you are running with gunicorn / uwsgi, update the appropriate configuration setting.

(2) a firewall on the pi is blocking access.  Depending on the operating system you may need to allow remote access to tcp port 80.  Depending on the version of linux you may also have to add rules for apparmor and/or selinux.  For example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --port 80 -j ACCEPT
```

(3) finally, the call using requests is slightly off.  It should be

```
requests.post(url, json=data)
```